# How can to link the colour of a point light to the RGB colour of another object in the same scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, drivers

In my scene I would like to link the colour of the point light to be the same as the colour of another object, which is determined by the shader applied to that  object. The output of that shader is driven/dependent on the rotation of an empty. How would I go about doing that? Is it possible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you drive the color of the light exactly the same way with the rotation of the same empty?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I did do that, but it only works with cycles. The node tree of the shader has a 'color temperature' node so I can't just write out the expression with drivers.

Comment: "The node tree of the shader has a 'color temperature' node so I can't just write out the expression with drivers." - Why? This is very confusing. Could you provide the full context of your problem? Could you describe it in full and provide sample files, screenshots, all the relevant info? What are you trying to do? It's too much guessing. How are people trying to help you supposed to know you have a color temperature node for example if you don't tell us that? What else do you have in the set up? What is it for?